# Unsatisfied link for function that worked previously

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I had a previously working JNI lib,
for some reason (I am not aware of any curcial changes) I can't use it anymore, as I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: de.ifi.lmu.sommerd.ftsserver.jni.IndexJNI.loadIndex(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>       at de.ifi.lmu.sommerd.ftsserver.jni.IndexJNI.loadIndex(Native Method)

So here is my test setup:

```
package de.ifi.lmu.sommerd.ftsserver.jni;

public class IndexJNI {

    static {
        System.load("/home/XXX/workspace/IndexJNI/resources/newLib.so");
        System.out.println("Loading library worked");
        IndexJNI.loadIndex("");
    }


    public static native void loadIndex(String indexName);
}
```

And here the relevant parts of the .h and .c files:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class de_ifi_lmu_sommerd_ftsserver_jni_IndexJNI */

#ifndef _Included_de_ifi_lmu_sommerd_ftsserver_jni_IndexJNI
#define _Included_de_ifi_lmu_sommerd_ftsserver_jni_IndexJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     de_ifi_lmu_sommerd_ftsserver_jni_IndexJNI
 * Method:    loadIndex
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_de_ifi_lmu_sommerd_ftsserver_jni_IndexJNI_loadIndex
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The .c file

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_de_ifi_lmu_sommerd_ftsserver_jni_IndexJNI_loadIndex
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass jc, jstring indexName) {
...
}
```

And this is my makefile:

```
test_gcc_lib: run_queries.o
    g++ -shared -fPIC run_queries.o SSA.a -o newLib.so
```

Comment: What is inside run_queries.o?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I had changed the call to static,
so now the signature was not correct anymore.
I just had to change jobject to jclass.